# How can I capture traffic on a Brocade XMR, MLX, CER or CES?

Tags: monitoring, brocade, wireshark

How can I perform a packet analysis on traffic flowing through a Brocade XMR, MLX, CER or CES without having to install a specific software on any of the remote endpoints ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best solution is to plug a computer running a packet analysis software like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) to an unused port and duplicate the traffic to this port. This is called **mirroring** and **monitoring**. Here is how to do this on a Brocade [MLX](http://www.brocade.com/products/all/routers/product-details/netiron-mlx-series/index.page), [XMR](http://www.brocade.com/products/all/routers/product-details/netiron-xmr-series/index.page), [CER](http://www.brocade.com/products/all/routers/product-details/netiron-cer-2000-series/index.page) or [CES](http://www.brocade.com/products/all/switches/product-details/netiron-ces-2000-series/index.page) :

First configure the *mirroring* port. This is the port you will plug you packet analyzer, `ethe 3/1` here.

```
Brocade(config)# mirror-port ethernet 3/1
```

Next, go to a port where the traffic you want to see is flowing (here, `ethe 4/1`), and specify this is a monitored port, and where you want the traffic to be sent :

```
Brocade(config)# interface ethernet 4/1
Brocade(config-if-4/1)# monitor ethernet 3/1 both
```

Note : `both` can be replaced by either `input` or `output` if you only want to analyze input or output traffic.

For more information, see the [documentation](http://www.brocade.com/downloads/documents/html_product_manuals/NI_05400a_CFG/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=Port_Params.06.15.html#1086983).

If you are looking for the documentation for VDX products, see [here](http://www.brocade.com/downloads/documents/html_product_manuals/NOS_AG_301/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=CH_Configuring_SPAN.35.1.html#1103819). For ICX devices, see [here](http://www.brocade.com/downloads/documents/html_product_manuals/FI_07400a_CFG/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=FI_Mirroring.27.1.html#1081553).

Comment: And for Cisco IOS switches, the corresponding question is here : http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/640/how-can-i-capture-traffic-on-cisco-ios-switches

Comment: is it possible to do this for multiple devices? Say I have 10 devices I want to get traffic from, is it possible to do this using a VLAN?

Comment: With this technique you will need to configure one mirror port per device. If you want leads, look into RSPAN (for Cisco) or Arista's "TAP aggregation" feature.

Answer (score 3):

Mirror sessions are great, depending on your needs (you mention 'packet analysis') sFlow might also be a great fit.

check the [brocade config guide](http://www.brocade.com/downloads/documents/html_product_manuals/NI_05400a_CFG/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm) (click sflow on the left -- can't figure out how to link to the specific page w/o removing navigation).

It's more or less as simple as configuring:

```
sflow enable
sflow destination <host> <port>
int x/y
sflow forwarding
```

You don't get all the traffic (sampling) and you don't get the full packet (its truncated), but depending on your needs and what/how much you want to analyze its a pretty good fit for a lot of things.
Tons of tools exist for capturing and analyzing sFlow data, that's probably a topic for another question.

Comment: Fun fact : I'm just about to configure it on a lab environment to work with http://www.pmacct.net/ !

And to link Brocade doc : open a link (not from the nav pane) to a new tab, and click the "Show nav" button, top-left. This should provide you a direct URL with the Nav panel.

Comment: Here http://www.brocade.com/downloads/documents/html_product_manuals/NI_05400a_CFG/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=sflow.75.1.html#1076515

Comment: You can use `copy-sflow` in a permit statement in an inbound L3 ACL as well.