# Capture traffic flowing through a Brocade switch remotely

Tags: wireshark, packet-analysis, brocade, mirror

I am currently doing packet capture through mirroring with Wireshark as mentioned in [this post](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/672/how-can-i-capture-traffic-on-a-brocade-xmr-mlx-cer-or-ces)

I can mirror the traffic to a port physically jacked into and analyze the packets redirected there w/ Wireshark. How can I, if possible, transport that traffic to a laptop or a remote device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called *RSPAN* - Remote Switch Port ANalyzer. RSPAN copies frames from a monitored port into a (dedicated) VLAN which you connect to the monitoring station.

1. Set up a VLAN between the monitored switch and the monitoring station.
2. Configure RSPAN from the monitored port into the RSPAN VLAN.

I found a detailed description for Brocade [here](https://www.manualsdir.com/manuals/54366/brocade-communications-systems-brocate-ethernet-access-switch-6910.html?page=731).

Comment: I do not know about Brocade, but Cisco also has ERSPAN that will actually route the traffic to a remote site, so you do not need a VLAN to span sites.