# Run out of ideas to troubleshout Ping issue Cisco IOS 3560 Switch

Tags: switch, cisco-ios, troubleshooting

**Summary**

Yesterday, four of the eight systems (connected to same VLAN, identical ethernet adapter settings) were able to ping `tweakers.net`. Today, another system is not able to ping the internet anymore.

As the [system site has been investigated extensively](https://serverfault.com/questions/617008/production-servers-can-suddenly-not-access-the-internet-anymore), the Cisco switch is perhaps suspected and has been analyzed as well (see `Switch analysis section` of the question), but the issue persists.

**Current situation:** [this Q&A](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/640/how-can-i-capture-traffic-on-cisco-ios-switches) regarding packet sniffing is read

**Question:** Which further steps can be done to debug while some systems can ping the internet and others not while ethernet adapters are identical and these are connected to the same VLAN?

---

**Switch Analysis**

*ARP*

```
Switch>sh arp
Protocol  Address          Age (min)  Hardware Addr   Type   Interface
Internet  10.10.10.2            147   Y               ARPA   VlanNum
```

*MAC-Address table*

```
Switch>sh mac address-table
          Mac Address Table
-------------------------------------------

Vlan    Mac Address       Type        Ports
----    -----------       --------    -----
 Num    Y                 DYNAMIC     Gi0/Z
```

*VLAN*

```
Switch>sh vl

VLAN Name                             Status    Ports
---- -------------------------------- --------- -------------------------------
1    default                          active    
Num  VLAN0Num                         active    Gi0/Z

VLAN Type  SAID       MTU   Parent RingNo BridgeNo Stp  BrdgMode Trans1 Trans2
---- ----- ---------- ----- ------ ------ -------- ---- -------- ------ ------
1    enet  ...        1500  -      -      -        -    -        0      0
Num  enet  ...        1500  -      -      -        -    -        0      0

Remote SPAN VLANs
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Primary Secondary Type              Ports
------- --------- ----------------- ------------------------------------------
```

*Running-config*

```
Switch>sh run

interface GigabitEthernet0/Z
 switchport access vlan Num
 switchport mode access
 switchport nonegotiate
!
```

*IP Interfaces*

```
Switch>sh ip int br
Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
Vlan1                  X               YES NVRAM  up                    up
VlanNum                10.10.10.1      YES NVRAM  up                    up
GigabitEthernet0/Z     unassigned      YES unset  up                    up
```

*Interface*

```
Switch>show interface Gi0/Z
GigabitEthernet0/Z is up, line protocol is up (connected)
  Hardware is Gigabit Ethernet, address is MAC (bia MAC)
  MTU 1500 bytes, BW 1000000 Kbit, DLY 10 usec,
     reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 1/255
  Encapsulation ARPA, loopback not set
  Keepalive set (10 sec)
  Full-duplex, 1000Mb/s, media type is 10/100/1000BaseTX
  input flow-control is off, output flow-control is unsupported
  ARP type: ARPA, ARP Timeout 04:00:00
  Last input never, output 00:00:00, output hang never
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters never
  Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 669
  Queueing strategy: fifo
  Output queue: 0/40 (size/max)
  5 minute input rate 248000 bits/sec, 34 packets/sec
  5 minute output rate 516000 bits/sec, 51 packets/sec
     6069964 packets input, 2943921646 bytes, 0 no buffer
     Received 99 broadcasts (56 multicasts)
     0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles
     0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored
     0 watchdog, 56 multicast, 88133 pause input
     0 input packets with dribble condition detected
     8562995 packets output, 4951152227 bytes, 0 underruns
     0 output errors, 0 collisions, 1 interface resets
     0 babbles, 0 late collision, 0 deferred
     0 lost carrier, 0 no carrier, 0 PAUSE output
     0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out
```

Comment: Please clarify... do you want to sniff packets, or see the output of debug commands

Comment: Question has been updated

Comment: If your question is merely about sniffing,  the question is a duplicate

Comment: Question has been updated.

Comment: I don't think sniffing packets will help you very much.Who is the default gateway? Routing setup properly? Any access lists? correct netmask everywhere? What about a firewall?

Comment: The interface counters could be misleading: clear your interface counters first by issuing `clear interface Gi0/Z`. You should also clear the ip traffic counters by issuing `clear ip traffic`.
Once the counters are cleared, replicate the issue and post the output from `show interface Gi0/Z` and `show ip traffic`.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to capture packages and analyze them with a packet sniffer (e.g. wireshark) the correct search term for Cisco IOS is SPAN (Switched Port Analyzer). [See this documentation from Cisco](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3560/software/release/12-2_52_se/configuration/guide/3560scg/swspan.html).

Regarding your problem: I don't think that you'll find anything in the logs.

I would start checking if the port System1 is connected to is still active an really still accessing the right vlan. (*show run*)

*sh ip int brief* and *show interface*  would be my first choices. Check if there are any error counters > 0.

There may also be some issues on the system itself. Check ip settings, proxy, DNS, ... (again). Ping the default gateway and system 2 and check if arp resolution is working.

Comment: Question has been updated. I will now check the documentation regarding SPAN.

Comment: i meant arp -n (or whatever the syntax is) on your client.

Comment: Output of `arp -n` is identical on all systems

Comment: The ping hangs on the default gateway, while pinging the DG works.

Comment: and there is something wrong on the default gateway.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to ping the default gateway from the computer then the switch has done it's job and is forwarding packets. I think you should move on to troubleshoot the configuration of the default gateway router instead of the switch.

Check the routers NAT configuration, more specifically the access-list which determines which source IP addresses to NAT. I've seen a similar issue in the past caused by a NAT access-list being:

```
ip access-list extended ACL-NAT-HOSTS
 permit ip 10.10.10.0 0.0.0.**15** any
```

When it should have been configured:

```
ip access-list extended ACL-NAT-HOSTS
 permit ip 10.10.10.0 0.0.0.**255** any
```

And thus only allowing the first 15 servers (with the ip addresses 10.10.10.1 - 10.10.10.14) from the network to access the internet.